# Don't destroy activity

Tags: android, kotlin, deep-linking

my app/activity (starts a tracking) can be started from another app. In my case the app is called from browser. I added an intent filter for incoming links.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="destination"
        android:scheme="mwde" />
</intent-filter>
```

This works fine. My problem is, that when user start the activity again, the onDestroyed function is called, but I don't want that in this case. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: You should never rely on the activity itself for statekeeping, because you can never be guaranteed that the activity will NOT be destroyed. Look into alternate forms of statekeeping like ViewModels for short sessions or Room/SharedPreferences for long term state. Maybe implement a loadLastSession() function that will be called from onStart()

Comment: Your question is not complete . Could u add some more details with a Usecase . the Statement `onDestroyed function is called` is not making much sense to me ..

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this flag in the app manifest
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode

Comment: Thanks in my case singleInstance helped.